# Can GraphQL server be built with Spring Boot version less than 2.x?

Tags: spring-boot, graphql-java

I am adding GraphQL schema wiring to my legacy microservices. I want to embed the wiring inside each of the spring boot services; The challenge I am running into is my project's Spring boot version is 1.4.5 RELEASE and moving it up to 2.x runs into others issues and would be ideal if I can get a basic graphql schema wiring done without updating version to 2.x. I see from documentation that minimal Spring boot version needed is 2.2.x in articles like this:
https://www.graphql-java.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-spring-boot/

Answer (score 1):

According to the gradle build file for the graphql-java-spring library (https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-spring/blob/master/build.gradle) the oldest supported Spring versions are:

```
springVersion = "5.1.2.RELEASE"
springBootVersion = "2.1.0.RELEASE"
```

You can try to compile it with an earlier spring boot version, but there is probably a lot of work to do.